# PC freezes±loses video signal and blue screen of death—while any playing any game for about ten minutes

Tags: memory, graphics-card, crash, bsod, graphics

I built a custom PC:

- **CPU:** Intel Core i7-5820K
- **GPU:** Gigabyte R9 280 Ultra Durable VGA 3GB
- **RAM:** ADATA XPG Z1 8GB (2x4GB) DDR4 2133 CL13
- **Motherboard:** GIGABYTE GA-X99-UD4 - Intel X99
- **HDD:** WD Caviar Blue EX - 1TB
- **Power Supply:** CORSAIR CS650M, 650W
- **OS:** Windows 8.1 64bit (before Win 7 64bit)

While playing any game—to ten minutes—the PCpc freezes, monitor loses signal with the graphic card, after a while the PC reboots itself or getting a blue screen with an error.

Through the program “blue screen viewer” at folder Minidump see the problem in these files that crashes:

- atikmpag.sys
- dxkrnl.sys
- dxgmms1.sys

Yes, this indicates a problem Graphics Card but when I tried RAM:

- **Dual-Channel (2x4GB):** Regardless of how they are involved, whether by manual or random, game usually fall into hours and pc freezes, need manually restart.
- **Single-Channel (1x4GB):** Only one 4GB of ram random involved in Single-Channel I have not noticed a fall even once. I tested both separately so the error in them is not i think.

I have installed all the updates and the latest software + flash bios from F8 to F11.

I do not want to play with 4GB, do you think that will help me buy another two RAM´s and try Quad-Channel, when dual-channel crash PC while playing?

Answer (score 1):

Some thing very similar happened to me. This was my process:

1. Create a bootable memory tester. Do this with both sticks of RAM in first. If that returns errors. Run it on each stick individually in different slots in your motherboard. Do your best to pinpoint the problem. If nothing shows up, move on.
2. I was upset when I had to do this also, but play games using internal graphics. Completely remove the GPU from the PC and play with it like this for about a week. Again, if it keeps happening, move on.
3. Check your motherboard. I bought my motherboard used (something I will NEVER do again) and it had issues. Go to Fry's or somewhere and try out a new motherboard. If that fixes, AWESOME. Otherwise keep looking. I don't know where to look after that. Maybe power supply.

Hopefully that works for you. I know how frustrating this process is. Just stick with it. It pays off.